# Updating ROM is stuck as TWRP does not see zip files

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, twrp, 3.1-honeycomb

In the process of trying to install 4.4.4 on my galaxyTab 10.1, I've installed TWRP 2.7.1.0.

At this point when in recovery mode I need to select the Zip to install, but none of the previously downloaded zip files are visible to TWRP.  Neither under the install command nor in the file manager.

I had backed up, removed caches et al. When rebooting in normal operation mode, those files are browsable.  Permissions are set to 777.

So I don't understand where the hang-up is?

Comment: This may not be the case but I should mention it. TWRP doesn't see a zip file under **Install** if the file doesn't have the extension `.zip`. (Tested on TWRP 2.8.6.0)

Comment: As an alternative, you can use **adb sideload** to push the zip file for installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Delta.  And the confusion.

A directory called '0' (zero), which had clockworkmod and TWRP directories where I had copied the files, while the clockworkmod had its own at the same level as '0' with the files downloaded earlier on.

TWRP apparently only sees the '0' directory.

Comment: Do mark your answer as [accepted](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) otherwise it will lurk in the unanswered questions, until an answer is upvoted here.

Comment: Will do in a couple of days (its my own and cannot do so until then)!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in `TWRP` there is an option to show `IMG` or `ZIP`. You should change it back to `ZIP`.